# No space between columns inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a `col-lg-12` div which has 3 `col-lg-4` the problem with this is there is no gap between these column and sticking to each other. I tried to increase the padding which didn't help. I have done so many time but this time i don't understand what is the problem

```
<div class=" col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="ckyc-content-div">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="pancard-card">
<img src="icons/pan_card_s.png" class="center-block" id="pan-card-img">
<div class="col-xs-12 card-text-div">
  <p class="text-center card-header">PAN Card</p>
<p class="text-center card-sub">Issued by the income tax department.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="poa-card">
<img src="icons/poa.png" class="center-block" id="poa-card-img">
<div class="col-xs-12 card-text-div">
  <p class="text-center card-header">PAN Card</p>
<p class="text-center card-sub">Issued by the income tax department.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="sign-card">
<img src="icons/sign_icon.png" class="center-block" id="sign-card-img">
<div class="col-xs-12 card-text-div">
  <p class="text-center card-header">PAN Card</p>
<p class="text-center card-sub">Issued by the income tax department.</p>
</div>
</div> 

</div> <!--CKYC Content div ends -->
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze5L4w3s/)  i did try other solution from SO but it didn't work.

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padd" id="ckyc-header-div"> add class padd and .padd {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `padding`, try with `margin`:

```
.col-lg-4 {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Of course, you will have to account for the increased size of the `div`s due to the added `margin`. Here is what worked for me:

```
.col-lg-4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: add margin will push the third col to new row

Comment: Weird, it looks fine to me in that fiddle I linked. I'll also edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: The above solution spoils the responsiveness.You can see that in fiddle

Comment: Ah, too bad, sorry I couldn't be of any help then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your *DOM* a little bit to get space among your blocks. Also need to change your *CSS* to maintain a proper spacing among them while in responsive view:

I have used `clearfix` class to clear out the `float` of its child elements like `<div class="col-xs-12 card-text-div">` otherwise it will behave abruptly.

**HTML** *(part only)*:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div id="pancard-card" class="clearfix">
          <img src="http://www.coca-cola.co.uk/content/dam/journey/gl/gl/icons/socialicon-twit.png" class="center-block" id="pan-card-img">
          <div class="col-xs-12 card-text-div">
              <p class="text-center card-header">PAN Card</p>
              <p class="text-center card-sub">Issued by the income tax department.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#pancard-card,
#poa-card,
#sign-card {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px; /* Add it for inner spacing for better content view */
  margin: 30px 0 0 0; /* Add it for responsive view spacing */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.3);
}
```

Here's the working [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/ze5L4w3s/6)

Comment: this works perfectly but i want to know how the clearfix class changes things here. A bit more explanation would be nice

Comment: @NaveenKumar `clearfix` is for clearing out the `float` of the child elements.

Comment: Naveen, if this answer was helpful, consider giving it an upvote. If it solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted (tick mark), so the question itself will be marked as solved.